# ¿Cómo corregir estos problemas para crear un proyecto de react?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm

```
PS D:\Universidad\Profundización II\tienda-bike-react-final> npx create-react-app frontend
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Ivan'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorMessage (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-message.js:38:39)
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:201:13)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:171:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:305:20)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:164:25)
La instalación de [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] fracasó con código 7
```

Necesito crear otro proyecto de react y no me deja, me manda este error. ¿Que puedo hacer?

Aparte del proyecto que estoy tratando de crear ya tenía uno pero con ese no tuve problemas

Comment: Podrías adjuntar tu código...

Comment: @RimuruTempest, que codigo pides si esta creado la app.?¿

Comment: @Shassain es verdad, perdón. Pero podría intentar con `npm init create-react-app frontend`

Comment: Revisa esta documentación https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 3):

Ok, estas en un Windows y tratas de ejecutar el comando:

```
npx create-react-app frontend
```

¿correcto?

Deberías revisar la [documentación oficial de create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

La primera pregunta ´normalmente sería ¿están *node* y *npm* correctamente instalados?
Puedes comprobar si tienes *node* y *npm* y que versiones con los comandos:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Suponiendo que todo está *aparentemente* bien. En la documentación de *create-react-app* se advierte:

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm
>   install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package
>   using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses
>   the latest version.

es decir que si ya instalaste *create-react-app* globalmente deberías desinstalarlo para usar *npx* (comando para crear proyectos con create-react-app en su última versión sin instalar esta aplicación en node). Puedes que no lo recuerdes, puedes ejecutar el comando de todos modos:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

y nuevamente:

```
npx create-react-app frontend
```

> Editado

¿Funciono? No se la causa concreta de tu error. La mayoría de las veces son problemas con *node*, contaminación por dependencias, etc. También puede ser que estés intentando crear un proyecto en un directorio donde el sistema (Windows) no te lo permite, prueba en el escritorio. Si aun no puedes crearlo desinstala npm/node, vuelve a instalarlos y prueba de nuevo.